# Privileges ACLs error when run remotely. invoke-command

Tags: powershell, privileges, invoke-command

I have a very simple script that works perfectly fine on a server, where I log on into the server and run it.

```
invoke-command -scriptblock { & snacfg workstation Computer /delete}
```

However, when I try to do it remotely, I receive "You do not have the privileges required to set system ACLs on files."

```
invoke-command -ComputerName SERVER -scriptblock {snacfg workstation COMPUTER /print} -Credential ""
```

I have also tried to call it remotely but get the same error message.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList \\SERVER\c$\users\USERNAME\desktop\SCRIPT.ps1 -Credential ""
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably leave the `-Credential ""` away, By adding this you bassicly telling it to run without an account I think. So either Remove it entirely so it will be run under the account of the current user, or declare the credentials like in the following 2 examples.

**Option 1**

```
$creds = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock { snacfg workstation computer /print } -Credential $creds
```

**Option 2:**

```
$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString "ThePassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("TheUsername", $pwd)
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server -ScriptBlock { snacfg workstation computer /print } -Credential $creds
```

Comment: Hi Kage, -credential "" is just an example where I type in my credential manually. Yes, i have tried both option and I'm actually using Option 2 for my other script on a different server. So pretty much I can do anything from the server directly, just not when I want to do it remotely.